# Loopback adapter breaks wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, loopback

When I installed the loopback adapter on Windows 10, the wifi stopped working. Disabling the adapter makes the wifi go back to normal. The wifi adapter stays enabled, but just can't connect to the network. This only happens on certain networks.